# PHP variable adapt the sql in expression

Tags: php, sql-server, expression

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_name IN ('Microsoft', 'Oracle', 'Flowers Foods')
```

Inside `IN` expression, I want to declare PHP variable. But My variable don't have the single quotes.

Here is My php variable `$Myvariable = 'Microsoft,Oracle,Flowers Foods';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

 $Myvariable = 'Microsoft,Oracle,Flowers Foods';

 $Myvariable = "'".implode("','",explode(',',$Myvariable))."'";

 echo $Myvariable;

 echo PHP_EOL;

 echo "SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_name IN ($Myvariable) ";
```

Output:-https://eval.in/726208